# NSDictionary - Get unique records choosing which keys has to be uniques

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries with N keys. I want to create an array of unique dicts which contains only some keys.

Example. My dict:

```
{
    "m_anno" = 2017;
    "m_c_ultimo" = "4.130";
    "m_cod" = 4522;
    "m_cod_art" = "*B";
    "m_des" = "SCRITTA BIANCA NISSAN";
    "m_ditta" = SIS;
    "m_prz" = "0.000";
    "m_qta" = "1.000";
    "m_sconto" = {
    };
},
{
    "m_anno" = 2017;
    "m_c_ultimo" = "25.020";
    "m_cod" = 4522;
    "m_cod_art" = "000/01200";
    "m_des" = "CABLAGGIO X TIMONE";
    "m_ditta" = SIS;
    "m_prz" = "0.000";
    "m_qta" = "1.000";
    "m_sconto" = {
    };
},
{
    "m_anno" = 2017;
    "m_c_ultimo" = "1.000";
    "m_cod" = 4523;
    "m_cod_art" = 000000;
    "m_des" = "BLISTER O-RING 3106";
    "m_ditta" = SIS;
    "m_prz" = "0.000";
    "m_qta" = "1.000";
    "m_sconto" = {
    };
},
```

I want to get unique values of m_anno and m_cod keys. Expected result:

```
{
  {
     "m_anno" = 2017
     "m_cod" = 4522
  }
  {
      "m_anno" = 2017
      "m_cod" = 4523
  }
}
```

Which is the simplest way?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that the pair of year and code `{ 2017, 4522 }`, `{ 2017, 4522 }`, `{ 2017, 4522 }`, `{ 2017, 4523 }` should be unified to `{ 2017, 4522 }`, `{ 2017, 4523 }`?

Comment: Exactly. I need unique values of year, code.

Comment: • Declare and initialize new `NSMutableArray`. • Loop thru the given array • In each iteration get the values for the `m_anno` and `m_cod` keys, create a new dictionary with those keys and values and append it to the mutable array.

Comment: @vadian This does not unify double dictionaries. It only reduces the dictionaries. And this can be done more elegant with key-value coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to iterate over the array (quelle surprise!) and put it in a collection, if the pair doesn't exist yet. The second task can be accomplished by using an instance of `NSSet` or `NSOrderedSet` depending on the requirement that the order has to be preserved:

```
NSArray *values = …; // You start with this
NSMutableOrderedSet *uniquePairs = [NSMutableOrderedSet new];
for( NSDictionary *value in values )
{
   NSDictionary *pair = @{ @"m_anno":[value objectForKey:@"m_anno"], @"m_cod":[value objectForKey:@"m_cod"] }; // Create smaller version
   [uniquePairs addObject:pair];
}
```

---

There might be a more elegant way. (Depends of the point of view)

Create an addition to dictionaries, that reduces the array to the desired keys:

```
NSDictionary( UnifyAnnoAndCodeAddition )
- (NSDictionary*)annoAndCod
{
  return @{ @"m_anno":[self objectForkey:@"m_anno"], @"m_cod":[self objectForKey:@"m_code"]};
}
```

Then use key-value coding to create an array of the reduced dictionaries and make a set of this:

```
NSArray *values = …; // You start with this
NSArray *pairs = [values valueForKey:@"annoAndCod"]; 
NSOrderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:pairs];
```

Well, at least it is shorter.

Comment: The first one because in my case "m_anno" and "m_cod" are parameters too and it was easier to create a programmatic version of the first version.